# NestJS Mongoose not updating documents

Tags: database, mongodb, api, nosql, nestjs

When i try to update a document its not working in mongoose. But in mongosh its working.

Can you help me why? Thanks!

**Heres my code:**

**Query:**

```
        this.messagesModel.updateMany(
          {
            _id: new Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data.msgid),
          },
          {
            $set: {
              message: encryptedMessage,
            },
          }
        ).exec();
```

**Messages schema:**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import mongoose, { Document } from "mongoose";

export type MessagesDocument = Messages & Document;

@Schema()
export class Messages {
  @Prop()
  msg: string;

  @Prop()
  chatid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  author: mongoose.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop()
  isEdited: string;

  @Prop()
  sent_at: string;
}

export const MessagesSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Messages);
```

Comment: Doesn't ```updateMany``` return a promise? Just make the parent function async and await the ```updateMany``` call

Comment: It returns ```{ acknowledged: false }```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are trying to `$set` message which is not present in your schema, hence it is not acknowledging your request, can you try changing it to :

```
this.messagesModel.updateMany(
      {
        _id: new Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(data.msgid),
      },
      {
        $set: {
          msg: encryptedMessage,
        },
      }
    ).exec();
```